# Computing the determinant of a complex matrix to check for an eigenvalue calculation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue, determinants

I'm trying to solve a classic eigenvalues problen on python: uFA + EA = 0 where u is an eigenvalue of the problem, F and E are (20x20) matrices and A is an eigenvector.

So first I tried to use numpy.linalg.eig(-F^-1E) to compute the eigenvalues u of the problem. The eigenvalues are complex conjugate. Then I tried to compute numpy.linalg.det(F^-1E+u*Id) to check the eigenvalues. It should return 0 or something really close to 0 but the result is around 10e50 which makes no sense.

Then I decided to use scipy.linalg.eigvals(-E,F) to avoid inversing F and to check the results I computed numpy.linalg.det(E+u*F) and once again the result is around 10e50 and not close to zero.

I don't understand where the problem comes from, I tried with a smaller problem:

-For a (4x4) matrix the determinant is around 10e-8

-For a (6x6) matrix the determinant is around 10e-4

-For a (8x8) matric the determinant is around 10e4

I figure this might come from the size of the matrix but (8x8) is not that big and the determinant is already a lot bigger than 0.
Also for the (20x20) matrix there are terms around 10e7 while others are around 1, might it cause a problem?

Thank you for you help, I really don't know how to make this work.

Edit1: Added the E and F matrices in (20x20) dimension

Edit2: I computed the rank of the matrix F^-1E+u*Id and it's equal to 19 while the matrix size is (20x20) so I think that the eigenvalues are correct. I guess that the problem comes from the determinant calculation.

Matrix E:

[image: Matrix E]

Matrix F:

[image: Matrix F]

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without knowing matrices you're working with...

Comment: I added the images of the E and F matrices